# SurfaceControl minLayer and maxLayer

Tags: java, android, screenshot

I'm trying to make screenshot using **SurfaceControl API**, but i'm can't understand how to use these parameter's:

```
 * @param minLayer The lowest (bottom-most Z order) surface layer to
 * include in the screenshot.
 * @param maxLayer The highest (top-most Z order) surface layer to
 * include in the screenshot.
```

I tried to put values from **-1000** to **1000** but in most cases it just return black image, in some - just screenshot of screen.

I dont need to capture whole screen, i need **content behind the view**, like **getDrawingCache** does, is it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

From [JNI](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/jni/android_view_SurfaceControl.cpp) source code

```
if (allLayers) {
    minLayer = INT32_MIN;
    maxLayer = INT32_MAX;
}
```

So, just set `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` works fine.

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) screenshotMethod.invoke(null, new Rect(), width, heihgt, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, false, rotation);
```